# Unity flips normal of the some times after Blender export

Tags: unity

I'm exporting a low poly character from blender to unity but it flips normals of some items, there's no reason to do that.

[image: Model on Blender]

[image: When I import to Unity]

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

I copied left arm to create right arm and scaled X axis to -1, if I import it like that it works correctly but if I do that and apply scale it flips the normal in unity,  now it works.